# Decision Diagram for Multiple Output Boolean Function in CUDD

Tags: binary-decision-diagram, cudd

I know that CUDD has support for ADDs (Algebraic Decision Diagrams) but I can't seem to figure out how I can use ADDs for multiple output boolean functions. The ADD for such functions would need to have multiple leaves, with each leaf representing a boolean output vector (maybe encoded as an integer). For example, 0101 as 5, 1000 as 8 and so on. Does anyone know if such DDs can be built in CUDD?